# Idiom or phrasal verb for "accept/deal with something even if you hate it"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

For example, what you say to someone unwilling to proceed with a necessay task:

> I know you don't like him, but you have to call him. He will help you find a job. (phrase here)

Comment: I am wondering whether we can use "Hobson's choice" in this context.

Comment: Or maybe suck it up?

Comment: ... also 'stick it out..'

Answer (score 2):

**["Deal with it"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deal_with#Verb) as a complete sentence would work wonders there.**

"4. To come to terms with; to overcome any difficulties presented by."

Answer (score 0):

**Put up with something/somebody**
Cambridge Dictionary defines it as:

> **put up with sth/sb**
>   :to accept or continue to accept an unpleasant situation or experience, or someone who behaves unpleasantly

**-I can put up with the house
 being messy, but I hate it if
 it's not clean.

-He's so moody - I don't know
 why she puts up with him.
 
-They have a lot to put up with
(= they have a lot of 
difficulties).**

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20up) (intransitive verb -put up with) also defines it as:

> to endure or tolerate
>    without complaint or attempt
>    at reprisal

-**You will have to put up with him.**